# How to use unlimited Frame-Sizes in JBoss-Netty without wasting Memory?

Tags: java, buffer, limit, netty, encoder

I explore **netty** to communicate Objects between VMs. I use `ObjectEncoder` & `ObjectDecoder` respectively to serialize these.

I quickly found out that this solution is limited to max 1MB-sized objects. As I intend to communicate larger objects and given I do not intend to limit this size, I used `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to set the maximum frame length.

Unfortunately it looks like **this value is picked up to initialize some buffers**, thus resulting in unnecessary GC-ing and very likely in OutOfMemory.

Is there a way to create an unlimited ObjectEncoder/Decoder while using DynamicChannelBuffers so that not too much memory is wasted?

Answer (score 4):

`ObjectDecoder` extends `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` which extends `FrameDecoder`.  `FrameDecoder` manages the decode buffer and it uses a dynamic buffer with initial capacity of `256`.

However, once you receive a large object, the dynamic buffer expands itself, but never shrinks.  If you have multiple connections that exchange large objects, your `ObjectDecoder` will all have a very large buffer eventually, potentially leading to `OutOfMemoryError`.

This issue has been fixed last week and a new release (3.2.7.Final) will be released this week.

Comment: Would it mean that with 3.2.7 we can use Integer.MAX_VALUE for lenghtdecoders without OOM issues?

Comment: Yes, if my analysis on your problem is correct.  However, you will still get an OOME if a client sends a very large object that doesn't fit into the VM heap.